# ASP.NET 5 on VS 2015 - Can't build or debug solution

Tags: debugging, build, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget-package-restore

I'm developing an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 solution.

Unfortunately I can't remember what happened but I'm getting a strange issue where the IDE doesn't build solution.

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> the following line appears in the output console:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: <My project name>, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

but nothing actually happens, and I can't close solution until I'd press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to cancel build.

I'm however noticing a few strange things.

1. The References section of the project is followed by *(Errors - see Error List)*, but no errors appear in the Error List.
2. In the Package Manager Console, no projects are present in the Default Project dropdown, and the Package Manager does complain about it.
   [image]
3. The Debug menu contains no options but Start and Browse With, and when I hit Start, I get an error message saying:

   > The debugger cannot continue running the process. Unable to start debugging.
   >   [image]
4. Running 'Restore Packages' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) doesn't do anything either.
5. When trying `update-package -reinstall` command in the PM console, I get the following error:

   > No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'Ackount'.

Unfortunately I can't remember precisely what I changed before it happened so I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: (1) Can you please share the `package restore log` from the Output Window? (2) What version of VS and tooling are you using (both are in the About window)? (3) What dnx version are you using?

Comment: @Victor (1) As I mentioned in my post, Restore Packages does NOTHING. Output windows is empty. Is there a log somewhere else? (2) VS Community 2015 (v14.0.23107.0), what tooling version do you wanna know (3) It doesn't matter. The issue persists after if I switched back and forth between v1.0.0-beta5 and beta6.

Comment: I've added another statement (5.) in my question.

Comment: Package restore for aspnet 5 project is handled by `dnu` not `nugget`. Running `update-package -reinstall` will not help. You need to run `dnu restore`. I'd like to know the ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 version. Also, what NuGet sources are you using?

Comment: Your comments helped me solved the issue. Looks like I had to download and upgrade the new version of the ASP.NET Web Tools. I've posted an answer, but if you'll post one, just comment on and I'll delete mine and mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've done and help me solve the issue, based on the comments of [Victor Hurdugaci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131768/asp-net-5-on-vs-2015-cant-build-or-debug-solution?noredirect=1#comment52179134_32131768).

- I've updated to the latest ASP.NET and Web Tools [beta6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48222).
- In a new command line, [`cd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490875)ing to my solution folder I've ran the command `dnu restore`.

Now it works and build like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with asp.net 5 beta 8. I removed the DNX Core target, because i am only interested in dnx451 for this particular project, but after doing that it wouldn't build anymore.  It just froze.  I tried dnu restore, but it didn't seem to do anything.

In my case, i just removed the project from the solution then did a rebuild.  I then added the project back to the solution, did another rebuild, and then for no obvious logical reason it started to build properly again - weird :)