# Visual Studio build stalls for all MVC 6 projects (MVC 6 projects do not build under VS2015)

Tags: asp.net, build, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Recently all of my ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 projects have stopped building within Visual Studio 2015 (Update 1)

I've tried many variations of patching / un-install / re-install for both VS 2015 and ASP.NET 5 as well as trying different version of ASP.net 5; the result is always the same....  The status bar says "Build Started..." and then NOTHING happens.  Canceling the build is responsive.

If I go to the command line for a project and use "DNU build", the project builds successfully and without error - But inside Visual studio, the build is stalled immediately and no progress ever occurs.  This is quite frustrating! any clues will be appreciated.

I did see this thread  [ASP.NET 5 on VS 2015 - Can't build or debug solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131768/asp-net-5-on-vs-2015-cant-build-or-debug-solution)  however none of these solutions worked for me.  Note that all other project types build correctly.  The issue is only with MVC 6 projects.

Does anyone know how to re-establish the application build logic for MVC 6 projects within Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Try building with both dnu and msbuid grim the command line

Comment: both dnu and msbuild build fine from the command line.  I have discovered that a new MVC 6 project builds fine inside visual studio just after creation.  Once the project is closed and re-opened building inside Visual Studio stalls as described above.

Comment: Perhaps another clue.  Once an MVC 6 Project is closed and re-opened, VS 2015 loses it's ability to build the project.  This also applies to the clean operation - which like the build operation, succeeds until a new project is closed and re-opened.  After an MVC 6 project/solution is re-opened, the clean operation yields the following in the output window.  1>Error: The operation could not be completed. The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was traced to a particular VS extension [HGVS] found at[https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/05a9706d-a3f5-4413-bcc4-4b83e3117e7b]

After uninstalling HGVS,the build and clean functionality from within VS 2015 Update 1 for MVC 6 projects returned to normal operation.

I do note the solution was a bit of trial and error.  Not much direct error information (if any) emitted during the errant behavior from visual studio. I did notice some other errant behavior particularly in the VS tools->choose toolbox items... dialog that inadvertently led me to experiment with removing/reinstalling extensions. (btw this dialog now blows up VS for some reason during load but overall it seems unrelated to this issue.)

Working backwards in time from my recollection of last install date for VS extensions (I didn't have that many installed anyway).  The HGVS extension appears to permanently stall the build process pipeline. Apparently I did not notice any bad behavior by the extension post installation as I was working on other project type.

Perhaps there is a way to get VS to log each step of the build pipeline and process.. which could have quickly shortcut the determination of the root of this problem [please comment if there is an easy way to do this]  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

~Compare the configuration if possible with your other co-workers(if any)

Comment: Thanks but I do not believe the issue is with any specific project configuration - I say this because the DNU utility is able to build the project with no issues.

Comment: Have you tried dnu restore, did you check the project files if there's something missing there.

Comment: Yes have tried dnu restore, update, etc.  and various old versions and latest. - all build OK with command line but fail to build inside visual studio.

Comment: The odd thing is that visual studio emits no errors or configuration faults, etc.  It simply sits there idle (otherwise normal) until the build is canceled. - VS 2015 Update 1 is deployed on Windows 10 Prof. x64 with ASP.NET 5 RC 1 Update 1

Comment: not sure if this will help you, but right click solution ->properties ->configuration check to see if the platform you are using is correct. Also see if you can do something from Visual Studio(Debug menu). Please mark if you resolve the issue.